# How do I enable cloudbees-jenkins-distribution docker push to push to my password protected private registry?

Tags: docker, jenkins, registry, jenkins-pipeline

Using this setup everything worked until I enabled `htpasswd`.

As far as I can tell everything is configured correctly so if that is truly the case; then is this a bug? I noticed in the pipeline console output it refers to `withDockerRegistry` where I actually used `withRegistry`.

## Config

To be clear this setup was working as a insecure private registry that jenkins could push to. There is, and was, no SSL setup. The ONLY difference was enabling `htpasswd`

Registry configuration

- I'm running my registry from a VirtualBox VM running using the `ubuntu/bionic64` image from vagrant
- The VM is provisioned with docker and has docker running
- The registry is running in a container using the `registry:2` image in the `nginx-proxy` network
- The registry is accessible at `http://registry.exp` my `host` file has `registry.exp` pointed to my `VM IP` at `10.20.1.29`
- The registry is configured with `htpasswd` using `docker run  --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn {{htpasswd_user}} {{htpasswd_pw}} >> /registry/auth/htpasswd`
- I can login from my browser.

Jenkins configuration

- I'm running jenkins in docker on my mac from the `cloudbees/cloudbees-jenkins-distribution` image.
- Jenkins is accessible at `localhost:8080`
- I've added my username and password to Jenkins credentials for `http://registry.exp` and saved it with the id of `registry-login`

App configuration

- I have `example-app` configured on github server
- `example-app` has a `Dockerfile` and a `Jenkinsfile`

### On my local machine I can do

- `docker build -t example-app --no-cache .`
- `docker login --username docker registry.exp`
- `docker push registry.exp/example-app`

#### My Jenkinsfile looks like this

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Deploy Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry('http://registry.exp', 'registry-login'){
            docker.build('example-app').push('latest')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running From Jenkins

`Console Output` in jenkins after the github repository is pulled and the docker image is built.

```
...

[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Wrote authentication to /var/jenkins_home/.dockercfg
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t portfolio-app .

Sending build context to Docker daemon     41MB
...

Successfully built 5cd890711511
Successfully tagged example-app:latest
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom

[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag example-app registry.exp/example-app:latest

[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push registry.exp/example-app:latest
The push refers to repository [registry.exp/example-app]

4dbf42572f81: Preparing
83fc1127b6ec: Preparing
31c9a8db3bb1: Preparing
487b885434b5: Preparing
d2968d4fb613: Preparing
8170f2d5c43d: Preparing
a464c54f93a9: Preparing
8170f2d5c43d: Waiting
a464c54f93a9: Waiting
no basic auth credentials
```